# How to identify CPU and memory usage per process on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, performance, memory-leak

There are many common apps available to show total system RAM usage and free.  However, my understanding is only a jailbroken phone has access to the APIs to access PER PROCESS memory usage on iOS.  How can one do this most effectively?

This link has a few example tools but they all seem outdated and no information if they work on iOS 5 & iOS 6. http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/troubleshooting-memory-issues.142660/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Xcode has an app called Instruments and you can use it to gather all sorts of CPU and memory statistics both live as the device runs and to save for analysis over time. This use of the tool doesn't require a developer account, any paid software, or a jailbroken device. You do need to set up the devices in Xcode's organizer to indicate you wish to use them for development and connect them via USB - just cancel out of any requests to manage certificates or developer profiles as you add each device to Xcode's organizer.

[image: instruments and iOS sampling]

Above is a one click, capture and you can dive as deep as I could imagine anyone needs by selecting extra data to be sampled and displayed...

[image: detailed instruments]

Comment: Wow!  That is an amazing tool I wasn't aware of.  I'm on a Windows computer so it's not immediately accessible but I might be able to borrow a friend's Mac or do an OSx86 hackintosh.  I'll leave the question open a little longer in case there's a way to do it on the phone itself (perhaps via jailbreak) otherwise I'll mark yours as Accept in the next week or so.

Comment: Do I need to "Add to Member Center" to do this?

Comment: @Znarkus I don't think so, but things might have changed since this was written...  Feel free to ask a new question with your iOS and Xcode versions if you want more details. Editing this old post might not make sense

Comment: As a heads up to everyone else, to use instruments for a specific app it must be signed with a developer profile. Most likely it needs to be yours, however I don't have another developer's profiles + certificate to test that one.